# Converting show-plan XML to graphical view plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssms, execution-plan

I am using the performance dashboard to set up baseline monitoring for my inventory of SQL servers. As per the performance dashboard available within SSMS, when i click on any query to view  the plan from ssms or via SSRS reporting it always give XML format.

Later i will have to copy that XML and save as .SQLplan to open it in SSMS.

How can i convert the same within SSRS to display as graphical plan, rather than going on that specific SQL server and copy paste the XML plan and then use SSMS to view the graphical plan?

Is above possible or one needs to know program this in JAVA.net or any other language to display?